# Why Hibernates ignores the name attribute of the @Column annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, websphere, db2-400

Using Hibernate 3.3.1 and Hibernate Annotations 3.4, the database is DB2/400 V6R1, running that on WebSphere 7.0.0.9

I have the following class

```
@Entity
public class Ciinvhd implements Serializable {


    @Id
    private String ihinse;

    @Id
    @Column(name="IHINV#")
    private BigDecimal ihinv;

 ....

}
```

For reasons I can't figure, Hibernate ignores the specified column name and uses 'ihinv' to generate the SQL:

```
select
        ciinvhd0_.ihinse as ihinse13_,
        ciinvhd0_.ihinv as ihinv13_,
...
```

Which of course gives me the following error:

```
Column IHINV not in table CIINVHD
```

**Edit:** I switched the log level of hibernate to DEBUG, and I see that it does not process the column annotation for that field. Tried several random things it just doesn't work.

Did anyone had this problem before? I have other entities that are very alike in the way that they are using # in their database field names and that are part of the PK and I don't have this problem with them.

Comment: Is it even legal to have a hash in the column name? What database is this?

Comment: @cletus - The question says that the DB is DB2/400.

Comment: @cletus - DB2/400, yes it is legal.

Answer (score 2):

You could try some kind of quoting:

For example:

```
@Column(name="`IHINV#`")
```

or

```
@Column(name="'IHINV#'")
```

Another option would be to dig in to source code [Hibernate dialect for DB2](http://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/hibernate/3/org/hibernate/dialect/DB2Dialect.html) and see if it contains anything helpful.

Of course, the easiest way would be to remove the hash from column name if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is the hash in the column name.  A [similar question on the hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=978397&view=next) suggests that backticks can be useful here.

Comment: This adresses the issue when you switch to a dialect that does not support the hash symbol. The hash symbol is used in many other tables in my database and I never got any issues. It is really with this table that I am having trouble. I might be facing a bug in hibernate. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @svachon - Are the other fields with hashes in them of the same type (ie, BigDecimal)?  Perhaps you're hitting a bug in hibernate specific to its handling of that type?

Comment: Yes there are other fields with hashes typed as BigDecimal. And I do have other working entities that have hash and BigDecimal.

Comment: @svachon - Perhaps check to make sure that the @Column import is actually the same?  Perhaps one of them is coming from a different package?  That seems unlikely, but the rest of the problem is ruling out a lot of more likely possibilities.

Comment: Yes the import is the same. I guess I will have to create views with column names without the hash sign.